# Erro ao abrir arquivos do projeto

Tags: visual-studio

Estou tentando abrir arquivos no meu projeto mas está dando erro quando tento acessar qualquer um deles. Consigo compilar mesmo assim.

[image: Erro quando clica para abrir arquivos do projeto]

Os arquivos existem, consigo editá-los fora da IDE, os nomes estão corretos.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Com qualquer arquivo? Inclusive os form? Não pode ser alguma extensão?

Comment: Sim. Acho que o VS que está com algum arquivo corrompido. Quando vou iniciar um projeto WindowsForms ele tá dando erro também. O jeito vai ser tentar reinstalar pra ver se arruma.